# why md5sum 2>&1 > /dev/null show error message

Tags: bash, io-redirection, hashsum

I have command like this:

```
md5sum -c {FILENAME} 2>&1 > /dev/null || ./upload {FILENAME}
```

and it show error if file is missing or invalid, I need to use this in order to hide the message:

```
md5sum -c {FILENAME} 2>/dev/null > /dev/null
```

why `2>&1` don't work? [It seems it's valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean#818284)

Comment: You should put `2>&1` *after* `>/dev/null`